# multiple sorting using knockout checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, knockout.js

I am trying to organize a observablearray that has inside 2 boolean ​​values and a price. I need via knockout and 2 checkboxes, filter the elements by these two values. Also sort by price ( ascending and descending) the displayed values . I don't put any code because I'm new in knockout and I can't see the way to make these actions.
Appreciate someone who instructed me.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I tried [this](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html), and I get it the checkbox matter, but the sorting using a value is too much complicated than an internet example. Greetings

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e0tr5ooa/ Very simple example.

Comment: THANX A LOT!!! THAT THE ANSWER I WAS LOOKING FOR! I'm newwy in this matters, so thank you again.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. in the future please make sure to show what you have tried as to demonstrate you put forth some effort and you're not just looking for someone to solve it.a failed attempt is better than no attempt.

Comment: Sorry, i'm newwy in the website, i didn't know that. Thanks again for your help. i'm now studiyin knockout deeply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer, I tried with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/e0tr5ooa/), but making some changes on my personal viewModel to supply my needs. So, I make something like this:

```
self.elementsToShow = ko.pureComputed(function () {
            // Represents a filtered and ordered list of elements
            var recomend = self.showRecommended(); //chekbox 1
            var special = self.showSpecial(); // checkbox2
            var sorting = self.currentSortDirection(); //sort direction: price or rating //ascending or descending, represented by an observableArray with that conditions and the //selectedSortDirection 

            if (!recomend && !special) return self.myOservableArray().sort(function (a, b) {
                //in case that no one of the checkboxes where selected but the sort direction was't by default
                if (sorting.price != null) {
                    var fp = sorting.price ? -1 : 1;
                    ap = parseInt(a.price);
                    bp = parseInt(b.price);
                    return ap == bp ? 0 : (fp * (ap < bp ? -1 : 1));
                }
                else if (sorting.rate != null) {
                    var f = sorting.rate ? -1 : 1;
                    ar = parseFloat(a.rating);
                    br = parseFloat(b.rating);
                    return ar == br ? 0 : (f * (ar < br ? -1 : 1));
                }
            });

            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.myOservableArray(), function (element) {
                return (element.recommended != "0" && recomend) || (element.offer != "" && special); //some other conditions for the relection of the checkboxes in the observableArray
            }).sort(function (a, b) {
                if (sorting.price != null) {
                    var fs = sorting.price ? -1 : 1;
                    ap = a.price;
                    bp = b.price;
                    return ap == bp ? 0 : (fs * (ap < bp ? -1 : 1));
                }
                if (sorting.rate != null) {
                    var fu = sorting.rate ? -1 : 1;
                    ar = a.rating;
                    br = b.rating;
                    return ar == br ? 0 : (fu * (ar < br ? -1 : 1));
                }
            });
        }, self);
```